# jquery select div index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

let's assume I have the following divs

```
<div class="category"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="category"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="category"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

I would like to access a specific div with class "category".

I know I can use this to get the first:

```
 $(".category").first()
```

But what if I want to get the 2nd or the 3rd? etc..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select an element using index.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

```
$('.category').eq(2) // 3rd element
```

*Note:* The index starts from zero.

**Demo**

```js
$('.category').eq(2).css('background', 'green');
```

```css
.category {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="category">A</div>
<div class="item">B</div>
<div class="item">C</div>
<div class="category">D</div>
<div class="item">E</div>
<div class="item">F</div>
<div class="item">G</div>
<div class="item">H</div>
<div class="category">I</div>
<div class="item">J</div>
```